# awk with two files, one possibly empty

Tags: awk, grep

I have two files, `file1` and `file2`. `file1` is a blacklist of words, and `file2` is tab-delimited. I would like to print out only those lines in `file2` whose first and second column do not match any of the lines in `file1`. Sometimes `file1` is empty, and in this case I want to print all of `file2`.

I believe this can be done with `grep -v`, and I'm curious how. But what I'm really interested in seeing is how to do this with `awk`. I tried

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$0]=1; next} !(($1 in a) || ($2 in a)) {print $0}' file1 file2
```

but this fails when `file1` is empty, because in this case `FNR==NR` is satisfied while reading in `file2`. This is a question that has bothered me for a long time, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If the second file being tab-delimited is important, just add -F'\t' to the posted solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
awk 'FILENAME==ARGV[1]{a[$0]++;next}!($1 in a||$2 in a)' file1 file2
```

Kinda like an ***ugly*** sibling of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16995160/970195).

Comment: +1 as this is the right solution except that `NR==FNR&&` is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a reasonably POSIX-compliant version of [`awk`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) such as GNU `awk` or BSD (Mac OS X) `awk`, use FILENAME and `ARGV[1]` instead of NR and FNR:

```
awk 'FILENAME == ARGV[1]                           { file1 = FILENAME }
     FILENAME == file1                             { a[$0]++; }
     FILENAME != file1 && !($1 in a) && !($2 in a) { print }' file1 file2
```

Strictly, the `{ print }` could be left off, but it is clearer when it is present (at least to my way of thinking).

Comment: Great Solution Jon. One question though. Would this be better, `FILENAME != file1 && !($1 in a || $2 in a)`? Both are giving the same results. So I'm getting a little confused.

Comment: @jaypal those two formulations (`!(a || b)` and `(!a) && (!b)`) are identical. See [De Morgan's Laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws)

Comment: @Jaypal: As Kevin noted, the two are equivalent under De Morgan's Theorems (Laws).  I prefer the uniform `&&` separator, but as long as it is parenthesized, wouldn't object to the alternative.

Comment: Accepted the other solution because it shaves off the first unnecessary line. But this is great -- I didn't know about the FILENAME variable. Thanks!